# How do I connect two wires to one GPIO pin?

Tags: gpio, pi-zero, retropie, gamepad

I plan to have a display (4-Wire SPI TFT LCD Display Module 240x320) connected to a Pi Zero:

I know that to connect the display I need to wire the screen to the Pi like so:

Display--------Raspberry Pi

BL--------------pin 12 (GPIO 18)

SCK------------pin 23 (GPIO 11)

MISO----------pin 21 (GPIO 9)

MOSI----------pin 19 (GPIO 10)

CS--------------pin 24 (GPIO 8)

RST------------pin 22 (GPIO 25)

D/C-------------pin 18 (GPIO 24)

VIN-------------pin 17 (3.3v)

GND-----------pin 20 (GND)

I also plan to connect two of these:

[image]

But as you can see, some wires from the screen and the gamepad pcb use the same GPIO pins? How can I connect both to the Pi?

[image]

Comment: "some wires from the screen and the gamepad pcb use the same GPIO pins" - Why? You can't use both functionalities at the same time, you would have to switch between gamepad and screen. If you want to use the screen and gamepads at the same time, then choose different GPIOs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting multiple wires to a single GROUND pin?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105849/connecting-multiple-wires-to-a-single-ground-pin)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check your wiring diagram to see if it's correct. The answer about connecting two wires, though, is this: Connect them via a breadboard or proto-board in lines that are connected inside the board or splice the wires together somewhere away from the board.

I see you're using stuff from Adafruit. You can get a breadboard from there (among many other places). If you're soldering pieces, their particular form of protoboard is called "perma-proto breadboard."