# Connecting multiple wires to a single GROUND pin?

Tags: gpio

I'm working on a project for my Intro to Computers class, and I need to light up several LED lights in a row with my Raspberry Pi (Model 4)(Using a breadboard). I'm sorry to say, but I am a beginner (baby more like), so I don't really know how to phrase this best. I need more GROUND pins than what I am working with, and I read somewhere that it's possible to use multiple wires connected to one ground. How would I go about doing that? I don't have any soldering equipment (or any experience whatsoever doing something like that). Could I just...twist the male wire end around another using the ground (like strip a small portion of the protective wire covering and twist around that)? I feel kinda silly just asking that, to be honest... Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use a breadboard

Comment: google for "Y jumper cable". Most approaches can be extended to `Y`'s with an arbitrary number of legs.

Comment: If you're using a solderless breadboard, just use a ground line. Do not just twist wires together and assume they'll stay together.

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest will work just fine.

Connect one wire to a Pi ground.  Strip the other end and twist as many other wires around that as needed.  Perhaps wrap some insulating tape around the bare ends afterwards.

You can do exactly the same if you need more 5V or 3V3 wires.

If you buy a breadboard you will see it dedicates long strips for ground and  positive voltage connections.

Answer (score 1):

I connect as many pins to a single ground on a bread board and I never have a problem, but I wouldn't do like a hundred if you know what I mean.